# Manual excerpt post in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with Manual excerpt in WordPress post.

I can see manual excerpt block while creating a post. But when I enter some text in excerpt block. It's not showing that text on main page.

The data is captured from text block as a excerpt.

Comment: This is not going to help you get an answer.. you might want to show us some code, explain how you have tried to solve the problem / show errors if any etc.. Or may be you should check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Hi Dear, I am trying to post image but it was showing I need 10 reputation to post the image.

Comment: Btw I am not getting any errors.

how I can make manual excerpts appear in the blog listing page?

Even when I insert an excerpt in WP, the blog home page still just pulls in the first 55 words of the text. What I would like to do is have different text in the summary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not familiar with wordpress theme coding, try to use `<!--more-->` quicktag when you writing wordpress posts. Here is a reference to get you to the right track.
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt

Comment: Hi Friends, Thanks for giving reply. Finally I found the page where I need to change the code. 

1. Blog.php
<?php if (is_single()) et_divi_post_meta();
if ( 'on' !== et_get_option( 'divi_blog_style', 'false' ) || ( is_search() && ( 'on' === get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_et_pb_use_builder', true ) ) ) )
truncate_post( 270 );  else { if ($currentPage==1 && $wp_query->current_post==0) the_content(); the_content(); }?>

Comment: 2. I have added this code in Functions.php

function new_excerpt_length($length) {
return 100; }
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
return '...'; } add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');

Comment: can you please guide me.. how to close this issue from here?

Comment: my problem is just resolved.. thanks!

Comment: sorry for the late reply. It seems your problem has solved. Glad to hear that you got the answer to your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't have excerpt function call in your template. Check these manuals: [the_excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt), [Excerpt](https://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt), [How to Display Post Excerpts in WordPress Themes](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-display-post-excerpts-in-wordpress-themes/)